# Can anyone tell me why Tcl fails to simply read a specific file? Also the contents of the file fails when doing a string length

Tags: tcl

The following 2 lines never return and no error is thrown using wish.exe. I have tried in tcl 8.4 and 8.6. File is successfully read with node.

```
set fp [open "test.lst" r];
 
set file_data [read $fp];
```

Ran out of memory trying to paste the contents of the file so here is a download link to test.lst

https://nextcloud.wardbenn.com/s/znE32yTTaGjm5wL

```
fconfigure -translation binary -buffersize 10000000;
```

also fails

Comment: Works for me. Are you perhaps doing this in an interactive wish session? Then the problem may be displaying a single 91MB text line in the console, which can be very slow.

Comment: yes I am doing an interactive wish session. How are you running it?

Comment: I put the commands in a file and run `wish file.tcl`. To do it interactively, make wish not show the data by changing the second command to `set file_data [read $fp];list`.

Comment: thank you very much. I am now getting the same results as you are and can even string length the results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running commands interactively, tclsh and wish will print the result of each command. A `read` command on a 91MB file produces a lot of output, which can make displaying it very slow. To prevent the printing of the result of a command, add a semicolon and a second command that produces very little output. Then that output will be printed instead:

```
% set fp [open "test.lst" r]
file6
% set file_data [read $fp];list
% string length $file_data
95513423
```